# Unable to cross-reference across frames in beamer

Tags: beamer, cross-referencing

I'm making my first presentation with beamer and facing some trouble with cross-referencing. Here's the particular problem I need help with:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Simple}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Allows including images
\usepackage{booktabs} % Allows the use of \toprule, \midrule and \bottomrule in tables

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Tom's Theorem}
\begin{theorem}[Tom's Theorem, 1948]
\label{john}
Something satisfying
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn1}
    a + b = c^2
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\label{eqn2}
    \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = 10
\end{equation}
\end{theorem}
\end{frame}
```

So this is one of the frames where I've labeled two equations I want to **cross-reference** later on. The labels are **eqn1** and **eqn2**.

Following this, I have:

```
\begin{frame}{Tom's Theorem}

\Cref{eqn1} along with \Cref{eqn2} constitute the system of equations we want to solve. Tom and John are best friends. Tom is in senior year.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This cross-referencing **does not work**. Why is that, and **how do I fix it**? What is a workaround to this? Thank you.

Comment: Please prepare a  complete and compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that allows others to reproduce the output you get. If I try to make such a MWE from the information you provided so far, I end up with a document, that behaves exactly as expected.

Comment: @leandriis Edited accordingly, let me know!

Comment: Add the `cleveref` package to your preamble.

Comment: That worked, thank you! Is there a way to cross-reference without cleveref by the way?

Comment: Depending on what you mean with 'cross-reference' then yes, you can use `\ref` instead of `\Cref` to get the correct equation numbers automatically, but then you need to add the word 'Equation' manually if you want the same output as with `\Cref` - so for example `Equation \ref{eqn1} needs to be solved`. For `\ref` you don't need any packages, because it is built-in in LaTeX. If you load `hyperref` (or `beamer`, which loads hyperref by default) then you can also use `\autoref{eqn1}` to include the word.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been solved in the comments.